# Translating C# functions into vb.net

Tags: vb.net, discord.net, c#-to-vb.net

[image]

I need help converting some of this code. Mainly:

```
private static void SetProvider(ServiceCollection collection)
     => _service = collection.BuildServiceProvider();
```

and the line below it. This is being used for a discord bot using `Discord.Net` with the music library `Victoria`. Can someone also tell me what this actually is? Just a side question. this uses static classes and there's not anything called static on VB.Net so what would be the best call here? I've seen some other posts from here debating whether to use `NonInheritable` Class or a `Module`. What are the differences and when it is better to use either one?

Comment: The Shared key word is as close as you can get Static

Comment: @Hursey . . . Indeed. `Shared` in VB.NET is the same as `static` in C#. Sadly it is not possible to add `Shared` to a class itself; it can only be added to class members. (By the way, VB.NET also provides a [`Static`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/modifiers/static) keyword, but it has quite a different meaning: it can be used with local variables inside a class method and it will persist that variable's value between subsequent method calls. Personally, I would prefer to use a private class variable for that, since that would offer more control.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equivalent `VB.NET` is:

```
Private Shared Sub SetProvider(collection As ServiceCollection)
    _service = collection.BuildServiceProvider()
End Sub
```

C# expression bodies are just a single expression body method, [MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/expression-bodied-members#methods) e.g. the following are equivalent:

```
void Greet()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
}

// Same as above

void Greet() => Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
```

Comment: thanks a lot! was a little confused on what the => meant. What would the other line look like when converted in vb? `public static T GetService<T>() where T: new()` would that be 
                                                                                                                                      `Public Sub getService(Of T)()  _service.GetRequiredService(Of T)  End Sub` or would it look different?

Comment: `public static T GetService<T>() where T : new() => _service.GetRequiredService<T>()` is equivalent to C# `public static T GetService<T>() where T : new() { return _service.GetRequiredService(T); }` so in VB.NET it would be equivalent to `Function GetService(Of T As New)()
            Return _service.GetRequiredService(T)
        End Function` it's a `Function` since it needs to return something unlike a `Sub`

Comment: @SOPMOD welcome to SO, if you have a new question for the next step then please open a new question, if this answer solved your original question then please accept it https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: thank you so much! I was scratching my brain for a while trying to convert this.

Comment: @kshkarin . . . Nice answer. Also good that you added a short explanation about expression-bodied members. I could only suggest that you add the translated templated `GetService(Of T)()` method in your answer (by editing it) instead of putting that information in a comment. That way all crucial information is included in your answer itself.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what you want exactly. VB.NET does not provide static classes. Instead, it offers modules, but those are not completely equal to static classes.

The module version would be:

```
Public Module ServiceManager
  Private _service As IServiceProvider

  Public Sub SetProvider(collection As ServiceCollection)
    _service = collection.BuildServiceProvider()
  End Sub

  Public Function GetService(Of T As New)() As T
    Return _service.GetRequiredService(Of T)()
  End Function
End Module
```

The class version would be:

```
Public NotInheritable Class ServiceManager
  Private Sub New()
  End Sub

  Private Shared _service As IServiceProvider

  Public Shared Sub SetProvider(collection As ServiceCollection)
    _service = collection.BuildServiceProvider()
  End Sub

  Public Shared Function GetService(Of T As New)() As T
    Return _service.GetRequiredService(Of T)()
  End Function
End Class
```

When using the class implementation, you have to be careful to mark all members as `Shared`. Additionally, you can consider the following:

- Declare the class as `NotInheritable`, since neither VB.NET modules nor C# static classes can be inherited from. (The corresponding C# keyword is `sealed`, by the way, but it will never be used in this context, since C# does support static classes.)
- Create one private (default) constructor for the class. That will make sure that you cannot instantiate the class. VB.NET modules nor C# static classes cannot be instantiated either.

Using VB.NET modules is somewhat more straightforward, but keep in mind that VB.NET modules have a little quirk. When accessing a member of a module, you are typically *not* required to prefix it with the module name. Suppose you have some kind of service class called `MyService` and you have implemented your `ServiceManager` as a module. Then you do not need to call it like:

```
Dim svc As MyService = ServiceManager.GetService(Of MyService)()
```

Instead, you could just call it like:

```
Dim svc As MyService = GetService(Of MyService)()`.
```

When using the former method, Visual Studio actually suggests to simplify the name and change it to the latter method. But when you afterwards add another imported namespace that also happens to contain a module that has a `GetService(Of T)()` method, you will get an error indicating that `GetService` is ambiguous, in which case you would be *forced* to prefix it with the module name (like in the former method).

I personally find this checking behavior in Visual Studio regarding VB.NET module member usage to be rather annoying and confusing. I prefer prefixing calls with the module name (for the sake of writing self-documenting code and avoiding ambiguity as mentioned), but I do not want to disable the "simplify name" hint/suggestion in Visual Studio. So I personally prefer a class implementation instead of a module implementation when implementing something in VB.NET that mimics a C# static class.

Or even better: I would avoid a static class design and switch to a "regular" class design when possible. Using class instances has several advantages, like using [composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition) (which is also an important technique used in many popular behavioral design patterns), simplified mocking/unittesting, and less side effects in general.

Comment: thank you! Is there any real difference between both `Module` and `NotInheritable Class`?

Comment: @SOPMOD . . . I have updated my answer and added some more information.

Comment: Wow! Thank you this was very clear and easy to understand the differences/advantages & disadvantages of both.